Change run script node version NVM
Currently, I am using NVM to manage version of node.
As guideline in NVM docs, I just use nvm use 18 and nvm alias default 18 to switch version of node.
It is ok for zsh but when I use debug (Run Script in vscode), it does not use v18, it uses v21 of node. Node v21 is current system while default is 18.
I just want to use v18 only and what is system of v21? I did not install it before. I am using macOS 14.
Thank you.
